# Making href only clickable & process to getPost

Tags: java, html, servlets

Using Java servlets **only**, I'm trying to get something similar to`<a href="something">something</a>` in my doGet(), but I need it to pass the parameter to the doPost(). Here is some of my code.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
    List < Folder > listFolders = (List < Folder > ) getServletContext().getAttribute("listFolders");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for (int i = 1; i < listFolders.size(); i++) {
        out.println("<a name=" + listFolders.get(i).getName() + " href='#' > " + listFolders.get(i).getName() + " </a>" + "<br/>");

    `
```

Using `request.getParameter()` how would I know/get whatever the user clicks? This assignment requires it to look like links and needs to be clickable. I've seen some other examples using .jsp but I am only limited to servlets for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
out.println("<a href='File?id=" + listFolders.get(i).getId() + "'>" + listFolders.get(i).getName()
                    + "</a><br/>");
```

Here, File is my java file name (File.java). To get the parameter in the doPost(), I use

```
Integer id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Edit: You dont need the java file name in the href, so it could be just

```
 <a href='?id="..."></a>
```